# Exists a way to configure cake so it uses inside DotNetCorePublishSettings the switch self contained

Tags: c#, .net, cakebuild

MSBuild has a switch "--self-contained" what publishes also the used .NET framework. So cake has a Function "DotNetCorePublish". Exists any way to set up that function so it delivers also the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [`DotNetPublishSettings.SelfContained`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNet.Publish/DotNetPublishSettings/):

```
var settings = new DotNetPublishSettings
{
    SelfContained = true,
    // ...
};

DotNetPublish("./src/*", settings);
```

Comment: That was it. Haven't seen it. :-)